# Legacy extension not loading on thunderbird-59

Tags: thunderbird, xpcom, thunderbird-addon

i'm trying to follow https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird/Add-ons_Guide_57#Removed_interfaces_in_mozilla57 to upgrade our extension to work a little bit longer. I'm testing with thunderbird 59.0.b2 and after not being able to refresh the source, i deinstalled the extension in the hopes of getting a reaction. Now i'm no longer able to install the extension using the instructions provided here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_extensions/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_7:_Installation This is not a webextension as they do not yet provide local file access, which we require.
Could someone throw me some clue sticks on how to proceed?

Comment: After more head banging, i symlinked my extension under extensions folder under thunderbird instead of my profile. Seems broken to me.